# How can I add an email to a lead in SuiteCRM via their API using sugaronrest in Java?

Tags: java, suitecrm

I am trying to add an email address to a lead in SuiteCRM via their API from our Java app using the sugaronrest library.

I can create the Leads module and the EmailAddresses module successfully, but I cannot create the EmailAddrBeanRel module.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String email = "name@domain.com";
    String referrer = "Testing";

    String leadId = createLead("Fake", "Lead", email, referrer, "Created by testing SuiteCRM Java");
    LOGGER.info("leadId: "+leadId);

    String emailId = createEmail(email);
    LOGGER.info("emailId: "+emailId);

    String relationshipId = createEmailAddrBeanRel(leadId, emailId);
    LOGGER.info("relationshipId: "+relationshipId);
}

private static String createModule(String moduleName, Object crmModule, List<String> selectFields) {
    String moduleId = null;

    try {
        SugarRestClient client = new SugarRestClient(crmUrl, crmUsername, crmPwd);

        SugarRestRequest request = new SugarRestRequest(moduleName, RequestType.Create);
        request.setParameter(crmModule);
        request.getOptions().setSelectFields(selectFields);

        SugarRestResponse response = client.execute(request);
        if (response == null) throw new Exception("Null response");

        String jsonRawResponse = response.getJsonRawResponse();

        if (jsonRawResponse == null || jsonRawResponse.length() < 2) {
            ErrorResponse errorResponse = response.getError();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            throw new Exception(""
                    +" errorResponse: "+gson.toJson(errorResponse)
                    +" StatusCode: "+response.getStatusCode()
                    +" JsonRawResponse: "+response.getJsonRawResponse()
                    );
        }

        JSONObject requestJSONObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(jsonRawResponse);
        moduleId = (String) requestJSONObject.get("id");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {           
        LOGGER.error("createModule error: "+e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return moduleId;
}

public static String createLead(String firstName,String lastName,String email,String referrer,String description) {
    String leadId = null;
    String leadSource = "Other";
    String leadSourceDescription = "Added from API";
    String status = "New";
    String statusDescription = "Added from API";

    Leads createLead = new Leads();
    createLead.setFirstName(firstName);
    createLead.setLastName(lastName);
    createLead.setDescription(description);
    createLead.setLeadSource(leadSource);
    createLead.setLeadSourceDescription(leadSourceDescription);
    createLead.setStatus(status);
    createLead.setStatusDescription(statusDescription);
    createLead.setAssignedUserId(assignedUserId);

    List<String> selectFields = new ArrayList<String>();
    selectFields.add(NameOf.Leads.FirstName);
    selectFields.add(NameOf.Leads.LastName);
    selectFields.add(NameOf.Leads.Description);
    selectFields.add(NameOf.Leads.LeadSource);
    selectFields.add(NameOf.Leads.LeadSourceDescription);
    selectFields.add(NameOf.Leads.Status);
    selectFields.add(NameOf.Leads.StatusDescription);
    selectFields.add(NameOf.Leads.AssignedUserId);

    leadId = createModule("Leads", createLead, selectFields);

    return leadId;
}

public static String createEmail(String email) {
    String emailId = null;

    EmailAddresses newEmail = new EmailAddresses();
    newEmail.setEmailAddress(email);

    List<String> selectFields = new ArrayList<String>();
    selectFields.add(NameOf.EmailAddresses.EmailAddress);

    emailId = createModule("EmailAddresses", newEmail, selectFields);

    return emailId;
}

public static String createEmailAddrBeanRel(String leadId, String emailId) {
    String emailAddrBeanRelId = null;

    EmailAddrBeanRel emailAddrBeanRel = new EmailAddrBeanRel();
    emailAddrBeanRel.setEmailAddressId(emailId);
    emailAddrBeanRel.setBeanModule("Leads");
    emailAddrBeanRel.setBeanId(leadId);
    emailAddrBeanRel.setPrimaryAddress(1);

    List<String> selectFields = new ArrayList<String>();
    selectFields.add(NameOf.EmailAddrBeanRel.EmailAddressId);
    selectFields.add(NameOf.EmailAddrBeanRel.BeanModule);
    selectFields.add(NameOf.EmailAddrBeanRel.BeanId);
    selectFields.add(NameOf.EmailAddrBeanRel.PrimaryAddress);

    emailAddrBeanRelId = createModule("EmailAddrBeanRel", emailAddrBeanRel, selectFields);

    return emailAddrBeanRelId;
}
```

The result of running the code above is:

```
createModule error:  errorResponse: {"statusCode":0,"number":0} StatusCode: 200 JsonRawResponse:
```

The email address and lead are created fine, but the email address is not added to the lead and no record is added to the `email_addr_bean_rel` table.

I'm either:

- going about it the right way, but missing some vital piece of data or process, or
- going about it completely the wrong way

Happy to receive advice in either circumstance :)
Thanks :)